# React-VR iFrame Fullscreen

Tags: iframe, react-360

Creating a React-VR app that I need to iFrame into an existing app. My question is regarding the fullscreen button. How can i either hide this button and manage within my other app or send a message to the parent that the button was clicked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couldn't find any official documentation for this but if you look at the implementation of [`VRInstance`](https://github.com/facebook/react-vr/blob/master/ReactVR/js/VRInstance.js) you'll notice a `hideFullscreen` option that hides that button.

```
// vr/client.js
const vr = new VRInstance(bundle, 'VRTEST', parent, {
  hideFullscreen: true,
  ...options,
});
```

To toggle fullscreen mode for an iframe you can use a library like [screenfull.js](https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js/) so you don't have to worry about the various cross-browser implementation details of the [Fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Using_full-screen_mode).

Just render a button in your page and make it toggle fullscreen mode for a DOM element on click.

```
const vrIframe = document.getElementById('vrIframe');

document.getElementById('vrFullscreenButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (screenfull.enabled) {
    screenfull.request(vrIframe);
  }
});
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Worth noting that the `hideFullscreen` option was only added in **v1.2.0**